# If 4 dice are rolled, what is the probability that three of the top faces show the same odd number and the other top face shows an even number?

Tags: probability, dice

I am currently struggling to solve the question in the title:

If 4 dice are rolled, what is the probability that three of the top faces show the same odd number and the other top face shows an even number?

I thought the answer was $\frac{3*3}{6^4}$, instead it is $\frac{4*3*3}{6^4}$.

Can someone explain the reason for that?

Comment: There are $4\choose 3$ ways that three dice can have the same odd number.

Comment: There are $4$ choices for the die that shows the even number.

Comment: Isn't it that the first odd die has a probability of $\frac{3}{6}$ to be odd, the next two need to be the exact same number, so twice $\frac{1}{6}$ and the last one needs to be an odd number so again $\frac{3}{6}$?

Comment: @ToTom yes, but you are assuming that the *last* die throws an even number. You should consider the cases when the even number can be thrown by the first, second or third die as well

Comment: Oh, ok now I get it. So I got the part right, I simply have to multiply it by four because I have 4 distinct chances of getting an even number! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no problem in your logic, except the fact that you are assuming that the dice are ordered, i.e. there is a first, second, third, and last dice, and in the end you are saying that the even number must come on the last dice. Indeed, the even number can come on any of the dice, and there are four of them, so the actual answer is your answer multiplied by four, which is the case.

Comment: Oh, ok now I get it. So I got the part right, I simply have to multiply it by four because I have 4 distinct chances of getting an even number! Thanks!

Comment: Yes, that is the point. You are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

It is:
$$4(P(1\cap 1\cap 1\cap E)+P(3\cap 3\cap 3\cap E)+P(5\cap 5\cap 5\cap E))=$$
$$4\left(\frac{1}{6^3}\cdot \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{6^3}\cdot \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{6^3}\cdot \frac{1}{2}\right)=$$
$$4\cdot \frac{3\cdot 3}{6^4}$$
Note: $P(1\cap 1\cap 1\cap E)=P(1\cap 1\cap E\cap 1)=P(1\cap E\cap 1\cap 1)=P(E\cap 1\cap 1\cap 1).$